# How to join json files using jq?

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have the following json file

```
[
  {
    "clusterName": "cluster1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "hostname": "server1",
        "dse": "6.7.5"
      },
      {
        "hostname": "server2",
        "dse": "6.7.5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "cluster2",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "hostname": "server3",
        "dse": "6.7.5"
      },
      {
        "hostname": "server4",
        "dse": "6.7.5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I have another json

```
[
  {
    "hostname": "server1",
    "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
    "processorcount": 12
  },
  {
    "hostname": "server2",
    "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
    "processorcount": 12
  },
  {
    "hostname": "server3",
    "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
    "processorcount": 10
  },
  {
    "hostname": "server4",
    "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
    "processorcount": 11
  },
  {
    "hostname": "server5",
    "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
    "processorcount": 12
  },
  {
    "hostname": "server6",
    "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
    "processorcount": 12
  }
]
```

I want to join these two jsons to produce the following output

```
[
  {
    "clusterName": "cluster1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "hostname": "server1",
        "dse": "6.7.5",
        "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
        "processorcount": 12
      },
      {
        "hostname": "server2",
        "dse": "6.7.5",
        "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
        "processorcount": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "cluster2",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "hostname": "server3",
        "dse": "6.7.5",
        "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
        "processorcount": 10
      },
      {
        "hostname": "server4",
        "dse": "6.7.5",
        "memorysize": "47.01 GiB",
        "processorcount": 11
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically the first file has the list of clusters dictionary. with nodes and I have a second file with the list of nodes dictionary.

The solution mentioned didn't work with multiple clusters.

Is there a better to do this in python instead?

Comment: Can we assume that each node of the first file will have an associated object in the second file?

Comment: @Aaron each node of the first file will have an associated object in the second file.

Comment: My jq foo is weak, so I'm not sure how best to merge this, but you can get the desired node array with `cat file1.txt file2.txt | jq -s ".[0][].nodes[] * .[1][0]"`

Comment: I believe you have a typo in the third code snippet of your question - your desired output. The outer array has two elements of which the second has the key `"clusterName"` with the value `"cluster2"`. This second element's `"nodes"` array in turn has two elements of which the first has `"hostname"` set to `"server3"`. But the second element ***should*** have its `"hostname"` set to `"server4"`. Right? - I suggest you consider correcting this to avoid confusing any readers coming here. (I cannot edit this myself because of the "6 character rule".)

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `jq`:

```
<file1 jq --slurpfile f file2 '
  {
     clusterName:.[].clusterName,
     nodes:map($f[],.nodes)|add|group_by(.hostname)|map(add)
  }'
```

This build an object using both files.
The first field `clusterName` is taken from same field of the second file.
The second field `nodes` is the combination of objects of both based on `hostname` (done with `group_by` command)

---

*A tentative answer to the below comment:*
I don't think that `-s` has any advantages here since you need both files in memory (instead of 1 with `--slurpfile`).
In order not to play with indexes, the idea is to test if the field exists or not before using it. You can do this with `?` and `//` operator. Together they from a sort of `if not ... then ...`.
Here is a possible solution:

```
jq -s '{
   clusterName:(.[][].clusterName?//empty),
   nodes:map(.[].nodes[]?//.[])|group_by(.hostname)|map(add)
}' file1 file2
```

As you can see, the difficulty in both scripts is to "normalize" the objects in order to perform the `group_by` operation.

Comment: Rather than writing to files, I would love to see a cleaner implementation of: `jq --slurp '{ clusterName: .[0][].clusterName, nodes: [[.[1][]], .[0][0].nodes] | add | group_by(.hostname) | map(add) }' file1.txt file2.txt`  It's tempting to ask a new question!  How would you implement this solution using --slurp rather than --slurpfile?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.  For me, the biggest advantage of `--slurp` is that I often use `jq` as a filter in which neither object is in a file and `jq` is just reading from the stream.

Comment: That is, instead of `jq -s ... file1 file2`, the invocation looks more like `cat file1 file2 | jq -s ...` (where `cat` is replaced by some non-trivial json object generator)

Comment: In the same conditions, I often use `json_producer1  | jq --slurpfile f <(json_producer2) '...'`

Comment: I have updated the problem description as the suggestions failed with multiple clusters.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using python instead

```
for cluster in clusters:
    for node in cluster["nodes"]:
        node.update(list(filter(lambda nodes: nodes['hostname'] == node['hostname'],nodes))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

> the invocation looks more like cat file1 file2 | jq ...

Here's a solution that assumes all the inputs are presented as a stream. This solution also avoids using the -s command-line option.

```
cat master.json hostnames.json | jq '
  # input: an array of objects, each with a "nodes" key
  def mergeNode($node): 
    map(if .hostname == $node.hostname then . + $node else . end);
  reduce inputs[] as $n (.; map_values( .nodes |= mergeNode($n) ))'
```

Notice that the -n command-line option has NOT been specified.

This solution also allows more than one "hostnames" file.